# When should I go to bed?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

Different harvest moon games have different penalties based on when you go to bed. I've been going to bed super early since I don't have much to do yet, but I don't know what my limits are.

What happens when I go to bed too late? What are the levels of "too late" and is there a single time I should go to bed before to avoid all adverse effects?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://fogu.com/hm11/basics/stamina.php,  the absolute latest you can go to sleep without major penalties is 5 AM, not going to sleep will cause a 30 point loss in health.

If you go to bed between 4 and 5 AM you'll lose 8 HP.

If you go to bed between 3 and 4 AM you'll lose 6 HP.

If you go to bed between 11 PM and 3 AM you'll lose 5 HP

Even though you could just hit the limit, every hour you spend asleep increases your stamina by 6 points, plus 50 for just going to bed.